# centos use wget download file(https) , available on the server ,but stopped in local virtual machine?

Tags: linux, wget

i need download a image:

https://gp1.wac.edgecastcdn.net/806614/photos/photos.500px.net/90241693/795b7a5900db5905631ebe7ff5aa141a5e0f59ce/3.jpg?v=6

available on the server(centos 6.5 64-bit), but stopped in local virtual machine(centos 6.5 64-bit):

```
[root@localhost ~]# wget 'https://gp1.wac.edgecastcdn.net/806614/photos/photos.500px.net/90241693/795b7a5900db5905631ebe7ff5aa141a5e0f59ce/3.jpg?v=6'
--2014-11-21 09:33:17--  https://gp1.wac.edgecastcdn.net/806614/photos/photos.500px.net/90241693/795b7a5900db5905631ebe7ff5aa141a5e0f59ce/3.jpg?v=6
Resolving gp1.wac.edgecastcdn.net... 159.106.121.75, 37.61.54.158
Connecting to gp1.wac.edgecastcdn.net|159.106.121.75|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to gp1.wac.edgecastcdn.net|37.61.54.158|:443... connected.
```

can anyone tell me why? and how? very thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like dns problem. Try

```
wget 'http://93.184.220.20/806614/photos/photos.500px.net/90241693/795b7a5900db5905631ebe7ff5aa141a5e0f59ce/3.jpg?v=6'
```